# React Native Expo Nested routing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a React Native Expo project and I'm facing an issue with React Navigation when trying to navigate to dynamic routes. I've set up my route configuration, but I keep encountering an "Unmatched Route" error when accessing routes like /analytics/:id and /analytics/:id/requiredReAuth. Here's a simplified version of my route setup:

These are two routes:

1. `"/analytics/:id"`
2. `"/analytics/:id/requireReAuth"`

The first route is working fine but second one show unmatched route.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvoVa.png)

inside _layout.js:

```
// [id]/_layout.js 
import React from 'react';
import AnalyticsApps from '../AnalysisFirstScreen';

const ItemDetailLayout = () => {
  return (
    <AnalyticsApps />
  );
};

export default ItemDetailLayout;
```

Below is first route when user click on required re-auth then navigate to second route.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzsY9.png)

I've tried setting up a React Navigation configuration in my React Native Expo project to handle dynamic routes like `"/analytics/:id"` and `"/analytics/:id/requiredReAuth"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `index.js` to your `[id]` folder:

```
 - [id]
    - _layout.js
    - index.js
    - RequireReAuth
       - requireReAuth.js
```